# Write variables to response.varfile

Tags: java

I am trying to read variables from my Java code using the following:

```
System.getProperty("application.version");
Variables.getInstallerVariable("sys.version");
Variables.getCompilerVariable("sys.version");
```

But these threw `NullPointerException`.

When I checked the `response.varfile`, I found only one entry `sys.installationDir`.

How do I add `sys.version` into the file so that I can read as required?

Comment: What is `Variables.getInstallerVariable`? What is a `response.varfile`? Are you using any libraries that contain this?

Comment: I've created my application installer file from instal4j. response.varfile is the file created by install4j while installing my application.

Variables.getInstallerVariable is the method to read those variables from the response file created.

Comment: What i really trying to do is, after installation of my application i need to update version in my database.

As of now, I'm saving version when i login application and configure fields and save form using System.getProperty("application.version").

The same is not fetching newer version when i execute after launcher.